# Ubuntu apt-get update 403 Forbidden in docker on Azure VM

Tags: ubuntu, azure, docker

I am trying to build a docker on azure. The Dockerfile starts like this

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev
```

The update command crashes with the following output

```
17:48:54 Step 3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     libcurl4-openssl-dev     libmysqlclient-dev     libssl-dev
17:48:54  ---> Running in 5a07e406e05f
17:48:54 Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
17:48:54 Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
17:48:54 Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
17:48:54 Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release
17:48:54 Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release
17:48:54 Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release
17:48:54 Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
17:48:54 Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources
17:48:54 Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources
17:48:54 Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
17:48:54 Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
17:48:54 Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:54 Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
17:48:54 Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:54 Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
17:48:54 Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources
17:48:54 Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources
17:48:54 Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources
17:48:54 Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
17:48:54 Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
17:48:54 Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:54 Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources
17:48:55 Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources
17:48:55   403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
17:48:55 Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources
17:48:55   403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
17:48:55 Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Err:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources
17:48:55   403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
17:48:55 Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources
17:48:55 Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources
17:48:55 Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
17:48:55 Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
17:48:55 Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
17:48:55 Reading package lists...
17:48:55 [91mW[0m[91m: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
17:48:55 [0m[91mW: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.[0m[91m
17:48:55 W: [0m[91mThe repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.[0m[91m
17:48:55 [0m[91mE: [0m[91mFailed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
17:48:55 [0m[91mE: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
17:48:55 [0m[91mE[0m[91m: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80][0m[91m
17:48:55 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
17:48:55 [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     libcurl4-openssl-dev     libmysqlclient-dev     libssl-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

The same Dockerfile build fine on my laptop and on other Azure VMs. I tried redeploying the VM, with no success. What makes this particular command fail on this VM and not others?
The azure VM is running ubuntu 16.04 (standard image from Microsoft), as is the VM on which it is working.

EDIT: created new VM, this time with the Azure docker image, and I hit the same problem. Still working on another VM that was created a few months ago.

Comment: How did you install the docker? Manually or by Azure VM extension? Also, your command runs in step 3, could you tell us what's the step 2?

Comment: I installed Docker manually following the procedure described in the Docker docs at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Comment: The command on step 2 is the MAINTAINER directive ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **exactly** the same problem trying to run a docker container with ubuntu 16.04 on Google Compute Engine.

**Quick fix** (for me on GCE):

Use ftp instead of httpeg

`sed -i s/http/ftp/ /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update`

My guess is that cloud providers have their own mirrors (make sense, just think how many times `apt-get update` is run in their dc...having local mirrors would save a lot of bandwith)

Maybe some http proxy are not redirecting the requests coming from the docker images to the mirror...

Comment: Thank you, it works! It's really strange, because I came across other threads which recommended doing this and I was sure that I had tried. Apparently I hadn't...